# I cant run my flutter project after updating to xcode 14... keep saying Unable to read project 'Runner.xcodeproj'

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

```
Unable to get Xcode project information:
 2022-12-01 13:57:05.376 xcodebuild[71564:226197] Writing error result bundle to
 /var/folders/6g/w7cqd0s54c33_20mrl4v2q640000gn/T/ResultBundle_2022-01-12_13-57-0005.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Unable to read project 'Runner.xcodeproj'.
        Reason: Project /Users/noel/Treegar/treegar-app/ios/Runner.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its
        project.pbxproj file.
```

i keep getting this error when ever i run flutter run or flutter build ios.

i dont know what to do... it works fine on android but not on ios.

ive updated xcode and flutter same problem

[flutter doctor -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3oyD.png)

UPdate cocoapod to latest version
update flutter
update xcode

Answer (score 0):

- try flutter clear and pubget.
  or
- try pod install
  or
- if it is not harmfull for your code try to delete ios folder and recreate it
  in your project. may be this can work .